# Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Active' of 'user' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have looked over a few suggestions provided and tested but still getting the error. The error only happens when I create a new user and they are added to the below list and I go to edit them all other users in the list work fine accept the last one.

[image]

The page that is having the issue is when I click on the edit pencil and it tried to load the user to edit the information but again only on newly created users like the bottom user in this case.

I did find one that said to make it `undefine || {}` so I changed mine to be `const { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = undefined || user;` but the error was the same more or less TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Active' of '(undefined || user)' as it is undefined.

UpdateUser.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

  const UpdateUser = () => {
    const { CollectorID } = useParams();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
      Active: '',
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: '',
      CollectorCode: ''
      });
    const { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = user;
    
    const onInputChange = e => {
      setUser({ 
        ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      Active: !Active });
    };

useEffect(() => {
  loadUser();
}, []);// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

const loadUser = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getCollectors/${CollectorID}`);
  setUser(result.data[CollectorID - 1]);
  // console.log(result.data[CollectorID - 1]);
};

const onSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/UpdateUser/${CollectorID}`, {
        CollectorID: CollectorID,
        Active: Active,  
        LastName: LastName,
        CollectorCode: CollectorCode
    });
  console.log(CollectorID, Active, LastName, CollectorCode)
};

    return (
      <div className="previewWrapper">
        <h1>Update Collector</h1>
        {FirstName} {LastName} | {CollectorCode} - {CollectorID} {console.log(user)}
            <form className="newUserForm" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="newUserItem">
          {/*Active or inactive User*/}
            <label>Active</label>
            <input
                type='checkbox'
                defaultValue={Active}
                defaultChecked={Active}
                onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                />
          {/*Collector Last Name*/}
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              placeholder="Last Name"
              name="LastName"
              defaultValue={LastName}
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
          {/*Collector Code First Initial Middle Initial Last Initial*/}
            <label>Collector Code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="CollectorCode"
              placeholder="Collector Code" 
              defaultValue={CollectorCode}
              onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
            />
            <button className="newUserButton">Update Collector</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default UpdateUser;
```

Comment: if(user) let { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } =  user ;

Comment: when I try this it gives me a message that 'let' or 'const' declarations can only be declared inside a block

Comment: All you have to do for that error is put brackets on the if statement. if(user) {  let { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = user ;  }. But you either have to define the variables outside of the if block and then assign them inside the if block, or use var instead.

Comment: I can get rid of the error if I change the it from ```const { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = user;``` to have ?? {} at the end like ```const { Active, FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode } = user ?? {};``` even though the error is gone I get no data for the variables even if I add them to the ```useState``` to define in the new ```{}``` or completely outside after the new line of code.